# Gulp Uglify keeps picking up unnecessary errors

Tags: gulp

I'm using Gulp to bundle all library files (jQuery, jQuery plugins, custom plugins) into 1 file and minimizing it with uglify.

However, when running `gulp` command, the console keeps throwing errors. I use gulp-util to see where the errors appear but when looking into the code, it's actually legitimate, nothing is wrong.

I know the code is not faulty because they are library files I downloaded from the websites, and they work properly when being included.

Not sure why uglify keeps picking errors up. For exmaple:

```
$ gulp
[16:51:19] Using gulpfile C:\wamp\www\example.com\gulpfile.js
[16:51:19] Starting 'lib-scripts'...
[16:51:20] { [Error: C:\wamp\www\example.com\app\webroot\dist\lib.min.js: Unexpected token: punc (()]
  message: 'C:\\wamp\\www\\example.com\\app\\webroot\\dist\\lib.min.js: Unexpected token: punc (()',
  fileName: 'C:\\wamp\\www\\example.com\\app\\webroot\\dist\\lib.min.js',
  lineNumber: 11296,
  stack: 'Error\n    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\\wamp\\www\\example.com\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1526:18)\n    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\\wamp\\www\\example.com\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1534:11)\n    at croak (eval at <anonymous> (C:\\wamp\\www\\example.com\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2025:9)\n    at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\\wamp\\www\\example.com\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2033:9)\n    at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (C:\\wamp\\www\\example.com\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2039:9)\n    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\\wamp\\www\\example.com\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2205:17)\n    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\\wamp\\www\\example.com\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2072:24)\n    at block_ (eval at <anonymous> (C:\\wamp\\www\\example.com\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2352:20)\n    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\\wamp\\www\\example.com\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2325:25)\n    at function_ (eval at <anonymous> (C:\\wamp\\www\\example.com\\node_modules\\uglify-js\\tools\\node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2330:15)',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-uglify' }
```

The code on that line is

```
...
ctx.lineTo(rightX, this.base);
ctx.fill();
if (this.showStroke){
    ctx.stroke();
}
...
```

Which is part of a library file and has no error whatsoever.

Comment: I truly thing that uglify is right: punc (() <-- ilegal token, please check where this is indeed on your source.

Comment: I do use that file in my app, nothing is wrong with that file to be honest. It only happens when I ugligy it